# How to convert jpeg , bmp, pdf to Tiff for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libtiff

I was wondering how to use LibTiff by using NDK in android. Could you give me a example? or Are there ways to find a good reference site in LibTiff? I heard that android do not provide the Tiff library.  Would you let me know any solution? so Anybody help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there please look at following link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5730/Bitmap-to-Tiff-conversion-using-Libtiff